# Magento : Homepage Products Block Add to Cart Leads to Empty Shopping Cart

Tags: blocks, magento-1, cache, addtocart, home-page

I have three custom module for best selling, new product and special product.
When I click on add to cart button of these products, it will leads to empty cart page and showing message `cart is empty`. While in whole site add to cart working fine.

When I disable cache, I am able to add to cart from here. For this I have increased cookie lifetime, gave 777 permission to session folder but nothing helped me.

Comment: maybe issue in **formkey**

Comment: form key is same throughout the page @PrasantaHatui

Comment: this either **formkey** or **cookie** issue. Compare both the page where works and the page where not works.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code to get the add to cart url. I think the issue is in the add to cart url.

```
$_productId = '166';
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_productId);
$_url = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product);
```

Comment: This has been already done, but issue is still same.

Comment: disable your 3 custom module and try one by one and debug them.